# Can I add Twitter-Bootstrap styles only to original GWT components

Tags: css, gwt, twitter-bootstrap, resourcebundle

I need to add Twitter's Bootstrap styles to existing GWT component...

I found more than one project but all of them creates new custom components for that purpose...

**I need to stick with GWT standard components and have my app L&F looks like TBootstrap.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will have a great job to do overriding GWT's default css. Your starting point may be the [Developer's Guide - Client Bundle](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.4/DevGuideClientBundle).

Some widget does not accept Bundles, so you may have too to override GWT css in the bootstrap html file.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can hack the basic styles with jQuery or overriding CSS styles, but the responsiveness, topbar and other things, I believe thats is pretty impossible...

You can take a look at [GWT-Bootstrap](http://gwtbootstrap.github.com).

Hope it helps..